# Application loading spinner

Tags: android, android-progressbar

I want to use the application loading spinner which Google Play application uses while bringing the contents of application.
How can i get that?

Answer (score 1):

First, it is not a "spinner"(spinner alone is a different component altogether) but a ProgressDialog and it is of 2 types. 
1. Spinner style
2. Horizontal bar style

What u see in the play store is a Spinning style progressDialog - [ProgressDialog](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog.html).

It is usually used with [Asynctask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

A small example here to make u understand how progressdialogs work: [android progress dialog example](http://mobile-development.org/index.php/android/android-progress-dialog-example)

Comment: Yes, ProgressDialog is the simplest to implement.  Needs only a couple of lines of code:

progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "", "Fetching...");

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean the spinning circle while it is loading something.
If I am correct, read on.
One of the ways in which android application developer can add moving images like those in GIF Format is by using AnimationDrawable class which is under the package “android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable”.This class uses multiple images as frames and displays them with particular animation which can be set using the class functions.

Firstly,the package needs to be imported and in the \res\drawable folder the images have to be copied which are to be displayed or animated.

Secondly,the images needs to be converted to Bitmap using BitmapDrawable class which is under the package “android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable” .The images are converted as shown below:

```
BitmapDrawable frame1=(BitmapDrawable)getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.w1);
```

where w1 is the name of the image in\res\drawable folder.

Thirdly,these Bitmap images have to be added to the animation.

The addFrame(Drawable frame,int duration) function is used to add frames(images) to the animation.The two parameters frame and duration are Bitamap image(frame) and the time in milliseconds for which the frame(image) should appear.The function setOmeShot(boolean) is used to set whether animation is to be played once or repeat.Pass true if the animation should only play once otherwise false.

Fourthly, the animation has to be set to the ImageView.

Lastly the animation has to be started.

```
animation.start();
```

For more info, visit this website: http://jannatyahan.com/android-application-development-tutorial-for-displaying-moving-images-in-android-application/